# Building a CMake subproject from the Qt Creator .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, ros

I have a project consisting of a structure of .pro files and I want to compile a CMake subproject inside. Now, I know that I can compile CMake projects in Qt Creator. In this case however, I would like to preserve the structure of QMake build system and somehow call the CMake subproject from it. The goal is to compile a ROS subproject as a part of my build process, including generating all ROS messages.